# Simple Python class definition not working

Tags: python

In the below code, the compiler is giving me the error "Local variable shouldStoreData" referenced before assignment. But I am assigning it first.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    shouldStoreData = False
    textPartDoc = ""
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
        if(tag == "title" or tag == "body"):
            shouldStoreData = True
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag        
    def handle_data(self, data):
        #print "Data is",data
        #print "valus of storeData is:",shouldStoreData
        if(shouldStoreData == True):
            textPartDoc  = textPartDoc + " " + data
            shouldStoreData = False
```

What I am trying to do here is that I want to store the data only when the tag is title or any tag within body.

Comment: couldn't reproduce on python 2.7.3. What version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first `shouldStoreData` is a class attribute.  The ones inside `handle_starttag` and `handle_data` are local variables.  In `handle_data`, you test the variable before you assign it.  Code inside the method doesn't know that the class attribute exists unless you explictly access it as a class/instance attribute (e.g., `self.shouldStoreData` or `MyHTMLParser.shouldStoreData`).

If you want `shouldStoreData` to be an instance attribute, then you need to write an `__init__` method and create it as an instance attribute:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.shouldStoreData = False
```

and then later refer to it as `self.shouldStoreData` in your other methods.

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to get a grasp of the basics of classes, attributes, and methods in Python.

Comment: Is an instance attribute the same as a class attribute

Comment: @Programmer: No.  An instance attribute is specific to the instance.  A class attribute is specific to the class.  Again, read the Python tutorial to familiarize yourself with how classes work in Python.

Comment: Wow. Why is it so for class attributes (in a nutshell)? Doesn't the class definition create a namespace?

Comment: @Programmer -- They're similar.  A class attribute is bound to the `class` (not to instances of the class).  The instances have access to the class attribute as long as the particular instance doesn't have an attribute of the same name via `instance.attribute`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: The class definition creates a namespace, but the code of methods in the class doesn't have direct implicit access to that class namespace.  They have to access it explicitly using the name of the class.

Comment: @BrenBarn Interesting. I thought they were in the same relationship as modules and functions (namespace-wise). So the class namespace isn't the "next outer" namespace for instance methods? Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to make it more clear :

```
x='outside'

class A:
    x='inside'
    def __init__(self):
        print x           #prints the global x
    def func1(self):
        x='changed'      #changes the global x
        print x,A.x      #prints the global x and then the class's x
```

**output:**

```
>>> a=A()
outside
>>> a.func1()
changed inside
>>> A.x
'inside'
>>> x
'outside'
```